# Angular/SignalR Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server

Tags: asp.net, angular, signalr

Using SignalR for my server and Angular for my client... When I run my client I receive these errors:

```
zone.js:2969 OPTIONS https://localhost:27967/chat/negotiate 0 ()

Utils.js:148 Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error

Utils.js:148 Error: Failed to start the connection: Error
```

I am guessing it is something with CORS... I am trying to implement a simple chat application. I am using the latest verison of SignalR:

Here is the github that contains the code for the tutorial I am following.
[SignalR Chat Tutorial](https://github.com/Ibro/SignalRSimpleChat/blob/asp-net-core-angular/AngularAspNetCoreSignalR/Startup.cs)

Here is my startup

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace signalrChat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            }));

            services.AddSignalR();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my client:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder } from '@aspnet/signalr';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private hubConnection: HubConnection;

  nick = '';
  message = '';
  messages: string[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.nick = window.prompt('Your name:', 'John');

    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('https://localhost:27967/chat').build();

    this.hubConnection
    .start()
    .then(() => console.log("Connection Started!"))
    .catch(err => console.log("Error while establishing a connection :( "));

    this.hubConnection.on('sendToAll', (nick: string, receiveMessage: string) => {
      const text = `${nick}: ${receiveMessage}`;
      this.messages.push(text);
    })
  }

  public sendMessage(): void {
    this.hubConnection
    .invoke('sendToAll', this.nick, this.message)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

}
```

I assume it may be something with cors. Thank you!

EDIT: I just recreated the signalr implementation in visual studio and it worked. I believe I chose the wrong settings on start up.

Comment: Did you try without  "http://localhost:4200" in .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");

Comment: Yes, doing withOrigins(); does not change anything.

Comment: I made a repository with a starter version working : https://github.com/WillieFitzPatrick/ng6-signalR.git

Comment: Can you please check proxy server settings, set internet option connection tab Lan settings -> Select automatically detect settings and uncheck proxy configuration.

Comment: @John What did you mean by 'I just recreated the signalr implementation' ? Please provide details. It may be usefull, I have the same issue. Did you create a solution from scratch or did you rewrite only client/server-side code? Or maybe you reinstalled/updated some of packages/libraries  (which ones) etc?

Comment: This a little late, but make sure you have the correct url http vs https was my issue

Answer (score 70):

```
connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
    .withUrl("http://localhost:5000/decisionHub", {
      skipNegotiation: true,
      transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
    })
    .build();
```

Comment: Please give us an explanation on how this solves OP issue.

Comment: An explanation is giving here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40aspnet/signalr/ihttpconnectionoptions?view=signalr-js-latest#skipnegotiation
"A boolean indicating if negotiation should be skipped. Negotiation can only be skipped when the transport property is set to 'HttpTransportType.WebSockets'.
That is why @Claims set the transport type to websockets. One drawback of this I believe is that this will not work in older browsers that do not support websockets

Comment: Thanks, they was to include options.SkipNegotiation = true; for DEBUG using localhost, on release it was okay

Answer (score 27):

I faced the slimier issue and I fixed it by adding

```
skipNegotiation: true,
transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
```

in client-side as @Caims mentioned. But I don't think this is the correct solution and feel more like a hack . 
What you have to do is adding `AllowCredentials` in server side. Anyway when it's coming to Azure you can't relay on that fix. So no need enable WSS only in client side.

Here is my ***ConfigureServices*** method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => {
        builder
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials()
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
    }));

    services.AddSignalR();

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

This is my ***Configure*** method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<NotifyHub>("/notify");
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

And finally this is how I connected from client-side:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
      .withUrl("http://localhost:5000/notify", {
        //skipNegotiation: true,
        //transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
      }).build();

connection.start().then(function () {
    console.log('Connected!');
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

connection.on("BroadcastMessage", (type: string, payload: string) => {
    this.msgs.push({ severity: type, summary: payload });
});
```

Comment: `AllowCredentials` (using `app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());` on `Startup.cs configure` method)worked for me!

Comment: hmm - I cannot get this working
If I try with skip and websocket then I get a 307 error (redirect) and without skip I get the CORS error.

Comment: found the problem, I had app.UseHttpsRedirection(), and it redirected to https://...5001. Once I disabled this it worked

Comment: I can confirm that adding `AllowCredentials()` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, and it turns out that the launchSettings.json in the part where it says signalRchatServer does nothing, the url that worked with me was that of the iisexpress, I say it because there are many places where they say that the url is the one below .

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I was pointing to the wrong endpoint.  I was using

`https://localhost:5001/api/message-hub` instead of

`https://localhost:5001/message-hub` (extra /api)

Also if you're using Angular, you're likely to get a Websocket not OPEN error right after fixing this one, so [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59550679/1288473) a link to save you from more searches.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem in my Angular application when I try to connect to Azure SignalR service Azure Function.

```
[FunctionName("Negotiate")]
public static IActionResult Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "broadcast")] SignalRConnectionInfo info,
    ILogger log) {
    log.LogInformation("Negotiate trigger function processed a request.");
    return info != null ? (ActionResult) new OkObjectResult(info) : new NotFoundObjectResult("SignalR could not load");
}
```

And below was my init() function code in Angular service.

```
init() {
    this.getSignalRConnection().subscribe((con: any) => {
        const options = {
            accessTokenFactory: () => con.accessKey
        };

        this.hubConnection = new SignalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(con.url, options)
            .configureLogging(SignalR.LogLevel.Information)
            .build();

        this.hubConnection.start().catch(error => console.error(error));

        this.hubConnection.on('newData', data => {
            this.mxChipData.next(data);
        });
    });
}
```

My problem was with the `con.accessKey`. I just checked the properties of the `SignalRConnectionInfo` class and understood that I need to use `accessToken` instead of `accessKey`.

```
public class SignalRConnectionInfo {
    public SignalRConnectionInfo();

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [JsonProperty("accessToken")]
    public string AccessToken {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

So after changing the code to `accessTokenFactory: () => con.accessToken` everything worked as usual.

Answer (score 2):

I waste almost two days for this and finally figured out,

**When this error occurs?**

- When you upgrade your existing SignalR server project to .Net Core
  but do not upgrade the client
- When you create the SignalR server
  using .Net core but you use traditional .Net framework for the client

**Why this error occurs?**

- The error occurs because new SignalR does not allow you to use old server & new client or new server & old client
- It means if you create the SignalR server using .Net core then you must create the client using .Net Core

This was the issue in my case.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it wasn't necessary all those stuff, I was missing the https instead http, and it worked like a charm.

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
  .withUrl('https://localhost:44308/message')
  .build();
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error due to cross origin. This solved it for me program.cs (dotnet 6) or startup.cs (dotnetcore < 6)

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
            .AllowCredentials()
        );
```

Notice that you should not open all origins if it is not a development environment or special cases.