# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5000/notificationHub' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 307

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr

I have implemented signalR both on my angular client and asp.netcore webapi. Currently I am getting the following error while the client is connecting to server

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5000/notificationHub' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 307
```

Could somebody tell me what the problem could be. I have set up CORS on the serverside. At the moment i am using port 4021 for the client as I have served the client using that port. The server is available on 5000 port

Server code

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHostedService<DashboardHostedService>();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => {
                builder
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4201");
            }));
            services.AddSignalR();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notificationHub");
            });
        }
    }
```

Angular client

```
export class SignalrService {
  private message$: Subject<Message>;

  private connection: signalR.HubConnection;

  constructor() {
    this.message$ = new Subject<Message>();
    this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(environment.hubUrl, {
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
      })
      .build();
    this.connect();
  }

  private connect(): void {
    if (this.connection.state === signalR.HubConnectionState.Disconnected) {
      this.connection.start().catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SignalR CORS same origin policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917125/signalr-cors-same-origin-policy)

Comment: Hi @Tom, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code and exception, it seems that your SignalR hub server listen to and respond over both HTTP (http://localhost:5000) and HTTPS (https://localhost:5001), and you configure your app to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS by calling `UseHttpsRedirection` in the `Startup` class.

If you specify the URL with `.withUrl("http://localhost:5000/notificationHub")` on Angular client side, which would cause the issue.

[image]

To fix it, you can try to modify the code to use HTTPS URL.

```
.withUrl("https://localhost:5001/notificationHub", {
  skipNegotiation: true,
  transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
})
```

Or not enforce HTTPS by removing `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` from `Configure` method in the `Startup` class.