# Failed to complete negotiation with the server - Angular + SignalR

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, azure, azure-signalr

I'm unable to establish a connection using Angular + Azure Functions using Nodejs. I know that the backend works because I created it using the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-azure-functions-javascript) and tested it with the client URL provided in docs. Messaging was working across multiple clients.

So now I'm trying to get Angular working. I've created a service for signalr in Angular to establish the connection, but I'm getting the errors

[image]
[image]

and on the network tab

[image]
I also tried replacing this code in service

```
  private buildConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("http://localhost:7070") //use your api adress here and make sure you use right hub name.
      .build();
  };
```

with this code

```
  private buildConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
      .withUrl("http://localhost:7070/api", {
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
      })
      .build();
```

per the recommended answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52913505/4350389) but then it just returns

[image]

I've never used SignalR before so I'm trying to piece this together from looking at several tutorials. I appreciate any help!

signalr service

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";
import { SignalViewModel } from "./signal-view-model";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SignalRService {
  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;
  signalReceived = new EventEmitter<SignalViewModel>();

  constructor() {
    this.buildConnection();
    this.startConnection();
  }

  private buildConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("http://localhost:7070/api") //c
      .build();
  };

  private startConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Connection Started...");
        this.registerSignalEvents();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error while starting connection: " + err);

        //if you get error try to start connection again after 3 seconds.
        setTimeout(function () {
          this.startConnection();
        }, 3000);
      });
  };

  private registerSignalEvents() {
    this.hubConnection.on("SignalMessageReceived", (data: SignalViewModel) => {
      this.signalReceived.emit(data);
    });
  }
}
```

just like from [Reference Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-azure-functions-javascript) link above, this is what my azure functions looks like

messages

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  return {
    "target": "newMessage",
    "arguments": [ req.body ]
  };
};
```

negotiate

```
module.exports = async function (context, req, connectionInfo) {
  context.res.json(connectionInfo);
};
```

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7070,
    "CORS": "http://localhost:4200",
    "CORSCredentials": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you can't connect your Angular with the SignalR function because de CORS polity.

You forgot to configure the CORS on your function.
[image]

Try with this configuration.

Comment: I updated my question to include host.json. I have it set to localhost:4200 since that's where Angular is currently coming from.

Comment: Ok, I see the error now, you put the configuration on the thost.json not in the local.settings.json. Also try firts with "CORS" : "*".

Comment: Whoops. I fixed that now. I moved it to local.settings.json now. Errors are still there though. Also if I change it to ```"CORS": "*",``` then the browser throws this error. (first line) https://postimg.cc/KKPNzHsM , but at the same time if I put ```"CORS": "http://localhost:4200"``` then I get the error  ```Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:7070/negotiate. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).``` Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, delete the CORSCredentials then. And try too with diferents explorers, chrome, firefox etc...

Comment: @user6680 Thank you and dont forget to config the CORS  on the azure portal when you publish your Function!!!

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help! I have one more question though. I got it working and the connection was established between Angular and backend, but something happened between then and now. Now when I run ```func start``` the negotiate function doesn't appear with list of other functions in console and it says ```The 'negotiate' function is in error: The binding type(s) 'signalRConnectionInfo' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.``` any chance you know how to solve this issue? I couldn't find an answer online. I might create a new post

Comment: You're welcome. Puff I m not sure, I work with functions on c# and that problem its cause you need the package, on c# was Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService, so maybe you lost it try reinstalling.